# Put javascript varibles in input box

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

```
<td>
<select name="arrivalMonth2" id="arrivalMonth" style="margin-right:1px;">
</select>
<input name="arrivalMonth" id="arrivalMonth" value="" type="hidden" />
</td>
```

I have this input box arrivalMonth, and trying to put Javascript varible arrivalMonth (which returns as "09") in the box.

```
var dateArrival = '20171029';
var arrivalMonth = dateArrival.substring(4,6)-1;
```

I've tried to do

```
document.getElementById("arrivalMonth2").value = arrivalMonth;
```

and "Cannot set property 'value' of null" is the return value..

Any idea how to figure this out?
I'm pretty new to Javascript, and running into so many problems..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No element with ID "arrivalMonth2" exists. Besides that it's bad practice to have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: You are have no element with id **arrivalMonth2** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use appent method for select

```
<td>
<select name="arrivalMonth2" id="arrivalMonth2" style="margin-right:1px;">
</select>
<input name="arrivalMonth" id="arrivalMonth" value="" type="hidden" />
</td>

<script>
var dateArrival = '20171029';
var arrivalMonth = dateArrival.substring(4,6)-1;


$('#arrivalMonth2').append($('<option>', {
    value: arrivalMonth ,
    text: arrivalMonth 
}));

</script>
```

or another method

```
$("#arrivalMonth2").append(new Option(arrivalMonth , arrivalMonth ));
```

```js
var dateArrival = '20171029';
var arrivalMonth = dateArrival.substring(4,6)-1;


$('#arrivalMonth2').append($('<option>', {
    value: arrivalMonth ,
    text: arrivalMonth 
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
<select name="arrivalMonth2" id="arrivalMonth2" style="margin-right:1px;">
</select>
<input name="arrivalMonth" id="arrivalMonth" value="" type="hidden" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to find an element with an `id` of `arrivalMonth2`, which doesn't exist. It may be a typo, though. I think you meant to put `arrivalMonth2` for the first `select` element.

Try changing the html chunk to this:

```
<td>
<select name="arrivalMonth2" id="arrivalMonth2" style="margin-right:1px;">
</select>
<input name="arrivalMonth" id="arrivalMonth" value="" type="hidden" />
</td>
```